# How to change Error Line background color in vscode?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have just started to learn flutter in vscode. But the error line backgrounds doesn't look good. Are there any way to close them? Here is the example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background of an error via the `editorError.background` property within `workbench.colorCustomizations`:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.background": "#00AA00"
    }
```

The above is a bright green, and looks like this:

[image]

If you mean the squiggly underline, the property is `editorError.foreground`.